# sed's 'N' command working intermittently

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Here is an example block of text I want to format:

```
<tr><td></td><td>tear a cat in, to make all split.</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td class="tdci">The raging rocks</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td class="tdci">The foolish Fates.</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>This was lofty! Now name the rest of the players.</td><td></td></tr>
```

using these two 'sed' commands in a script:

```
sed -ri '/^<tr><td><\/td><td>/N;s/(\n<tr><td><\/td><td class="tdci">)/\n<tr><td>\&nbsp;<\/td><\/tr>\1/' "$f"   #insert table row with empty data fields (blank line) above first line with 'class="tdci"'
sed -ri '/^<tr><td><\/td><td class="tdci">/N;s/(\n<tr><td><\/td><td>)/\n<tr><td>\&nbsp;<\/td><\/tr>\1/' "$f"   #insert table row with empty data fields (blank line) after last line with 'class="tdci"'
```

here is the result:

```
<tr><td></td><td>tear a cat in, to make all split.</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td class="tdci">The raging rocks</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td class="tdci">The foolish Fates.</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>This was lofty! Now name the rest of the players.</td><td></td></tr>
```

So the first `sed` command works by inserting a blank table row above the first line with `class="tdci"`, but the almost identical second `sed` command meant to insert a blank table row after the last line with `class="tdci"` does not work.

I usually save these kinds of edits, editing between multiple lines, for vim since I never have problems with its similar command, but for some reason `sed`'s" `N;s/` has always been hit and miss for me, as in this example, where one instance works fine, yet a second does not. The script removes all leading/trailing whitespace and any Winblowz carriage returns (`\r`) before these commands get run.

Since I have a large number of files to edit I would of course prefer to get this working in a script if anyone might be able to see anything obvious I am doing wrong.

**Additional details:**

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am running `sed` in Linux (Debian stable)

Comment: There are plenty of HTML parsers and pretty printers out there; make use of those.

Comment: On what OS are you doing this? What version of sed?

Comment: @devnull I appreciate the HTML advice, but let's stay focused. My question is about the behaviour of a particular 'sed' command; the text I am trying to manipulate might quite possibly be some format other than HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start small! Here's a simpler test case for what you're doing:

```
a1
b1
b2
a2
```

Here is your code translated for this test case, trying to insert `c1` before the first "b" and `c2` after the last:

```
sed -ri '/a/N; s/(\nb)/\nc1\1/' file
sed -ri '/b/N; s/(\na)/\nc2\1/' file
```

The first command, like you say, appears to work:

```
a1
c1
b1
b2
a1
```

The second does not, and just gives you the same result as above rather than inserting `c2`.

Here's what you probably thought would happen, with incorrect parts in bold:

1. `a1` is read and printed.
2. `c1` is read and printed.
3. `b1` is read.

   - It matches `/b/`, and `b2` is read with `N`.
   - It doesn't match `\na`.
   - **`b1` is printed**
4. **`b2` is read a second time**.

   - It matches `/b/`, and `a` is read with `N`.
   - It matches `\na`. `c2` is appended.
   - `b2\nc2\na` is printed.

Here is what actually happens,

1. `a1` is read and printed.
2. `c1` is read and printed.
3. `b1` is read.

   - It matches `/b/`, and `b2` is read with `N`.
   - It doesn't match `\na`.
   - **`b1\nb2` is printed**
4. **`a2` is read and printed**, because `b2` has already been read above.

Here's a working command:

```
sed -ri '/b/ { :b; N; s/\na/\nc2&/; te; P; D; bb; }; :e;' file
```

In pseudocode -- with roughly corresponding sed part in comments -- this is:

```
if (input.matches("b")) {                               // /b/ {
  while(true) {                                         // :b
    input += "\n" + readline();                         // N
    if(input.matches("\na")) {                          // s/\na/ ..
      input = input.replace("(\na)", "\nc2\1");         // .. \nc2&/
      goto exit;                                        // te
    }
    print(input.substring(0, input.indexOf('\n'));      // P
    input = input.substring(input.indexOf('\n') + 1);   // D
  }                                                     // bb
}                                                       // }
:exit                                                   // :e
```

Translated back to your data:

```
sed -ri '/^<tr><td><\/td><td class="tdci">/ { :b; N; s/(\n<tr><td><\/td><td>)/\n<tr><td>\&nbsp;<\/td><\/tr>\1/; te; P; D; bb; }; :e' "$f"
```

Comment: @tog: wow! it works, but to be honest, I am lost and will have to start reading about 'sed' options you detail to help make heads or tails of the how and why.

Comment: +1; great analysis; your pseudocode is missing the string-replacement command; would be even more helpful if you directly related the pseudo-commands to their `sed` counterparts with comments.

Answer (score 2):

[@that other guy's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22773023/45375) shows how to do it with `sed`.

However, `sed` can be a brain bender when it comes to problems like these that are somewhat procedural in nature, so here's an **`awk` solution that is probably easier to understand**:

```
awk -v blockRegex='^<tr><td><\/td><td class="tdci">' \
    -v lineToInsert='<tr><td>\&nbsp;<\/td><\/tr>' \
  '
    # Print a line BEFORE the FIRST line matching `blockRegex`.
  $0 ~ blockRegex { if (!afterFirst) {print lineToInsert; afterFirst=inBlock=1} }
    # Print a line AFTER the LAST (contiguous) line matching `blockRegex`.
  inBlock && $0 !~ blockRegex { print lineToInsert; afterFirst=inBlock=0 }
    # Print the input line.
  { print }
  ' \
  file
```

Note that this could be optimized further, but I wanted to keep it simpler to clarify the logic.

- `blockRegex` is passed in as a variable (with option `-v`) to **identify blocks of contiguous lines before and after which a line is to be inserted** - with the line to be inserted passed in as variable `lineToInsert`.
- `$0 ~ blockRegex` matches each line in a block of lines of interest and prints the line to insert if it's the *first* line in the block, as indicated by status variable `afterFirst`; status variable `inBlock` indicates that the line at hand is inside a block of interest.
- `inBlock && $0 !~ blockRegex` matches the *first* line *after* the block of interest and prints the line to insert, then resets the status variables.
- `print` simply prints the input line as is.

Note that the use of the status variables relies on uninitialized variables in `awk` defaulting to `0` (which is treated as `false` in a Boolean context; similarly, a non-zero value evaluates as `true`).